# Gatling Error: There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/simulations

Tags: gatling

I'm new to Gatling and I'm trying to use ./gatling.sh to open a simulation script but I'm getting the following error:

> There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in
>   user-files/simulations

I can view multiple scripts within the user-files/simulations directory but still get the error.

Does anyone have any ideas why Gatling is not finding the simulation script?

Comment: Have you checked if your scripts extend the Simulation class? Like so `class MyScript extends Simulation` Otherwise they won't be found by Gatling.

Comment: yes, the scripts all extend the simulation class.

Comment: I am facing the same error on Mac. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem in Windows, when trying to run the basic gatling simulation. Gatling version 2.3.1

Comment: Gatling 3.0.3, Linux Alpine, 1.8 OpenJDK here. JAVA_HOME is set correctly. Stumped.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR**
The error doesn't necessarily mean that there are no scripts, but that the gatling was not able to find *compiled* script.

**In details**

I was facing a similar error, but it was something like this:

```
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
There is no simulation script. Please check that your scripts are in user-files/simulations
```

So I opened the `gatling.bat` file and changed the parameter of `set JAVA_OPTS` from `-Xmx1G` to be `-Xmx512M`:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx512M...
```

After I did that, the gatling was able to really start running, compiling the files and display:

```
Choose a simulation number:
 [0] computerdatabase.BasicSimulation
 [1] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep01
 [2] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep02
 [3] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep03
 [4] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep04
 [5] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep05
```

Answer (score 5):

`Gatling` can only run with `Jdk8`. For windows, you can install multiple `JDK` as well. After install `JDK8`, go to your `bin/gatling.bat`, right click on that and select **Edit**.

Replace all `%JAVA_HOME%` with the your `JDK8` path.

Example

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe

to

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set.

On a Mac, you can type "env" in Terminal to show all of your environment variables. On Windows, type "set" in cmd to get a list.

You should see something like:

> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 2):

**You should first check your scala code and remove all the errors from your file/all the files, even if any one of the file has some issues then none of the test is going to get compiled and run.**

1. Please check the package names and the file actually belongs to same package or not. [this was the issue in my case.]
2. Check indentation, it should not mismatch. [this was also there in my case]
3. Then you can check replacing JAVA_HOME in gatling.bat or gatling.sh file with the actual path as mentioned by some guys here.
4. Lastly you can change the JAVA_OPTS like mentioned by some one in above comments.[from -Xmx1G to be -Xmx512M]

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by JAVA_HOME wrongly set.

Following Gatling documentation the system needs JDK8 to run:

https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/quickstart

Does not support JDK9 at the moment.

To check if you have JDK8 installed on Mac for example you can do:

```
# List Java versions installed
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

if you get:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
9.0.4, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Means that there is only JDK9 installed. Then you have to download and instal JDK8 (in Mac you can have several JDK installed), now the previous command returns:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    9.0.4, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.4" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and we can set JAVA_HOME with JDK8:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

After these steps running `gatling.sh` should not show the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add the next code to **logback.xml**

```
<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

And start **gatling.sh**

P.S. it's magical